# Not too sure why strtok is not working the way I want it to

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, 2d, strtok

EDIT 2: Okay, all i did was change the malloc for the char's pointed to by surname[i] to 50 bytes, and my program works fine. Can anyone explain why? I think it is because strtok returns a pointer to an string that is greater than 16 bytes and I'm trying to assign that string to an dynamically allocated 16 byte array. Thanks.
I'm trying to parse a lines from a file and store them into 3 parallel arrays. The text file I am reading from has this in it:

Ryan, Elizabeth O.\n
  McIntyre, O. J.\n
  Cauble-Chantrenne, Kristin K.\n
  Larson, Lois F.\n
  Thorpe, Trinity R.\n
  Ruiz, Pedro M.\n

The format for each person is surname, firstname/initial, and middle initial
I have 3 parallel arrays: char **surname, char **first, and char *middle_init
I have already checked that my calls to Fgets work. My algorithm was to store each line first into surname[i] and parse it into its components and then into the 3 parallel arrays.

PROBLEM:
My program works, but for some reason, it doesn't work for "Cauble-Chantrenne, Kristin K." When I print out surname[2] and first[2], I get:
Cauble-Chantren
KristLarson

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char **surname, **first;
  char *middle_init;
  int num_people;
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &num_people);
  surname = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * num_people);
  first = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * num_people);
  middle_init = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * num_people);
  read_names(fp, num_people, surname, first, middle_init);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("%s\n", surname[2]);
  printf("%s\n", first[2]);
  sort(num_people, surname, first, middle_init);
  write_names(num_people, argv[2], surname, first, middle_init);
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what my problem is? Thankyou!!! I am sure my problem has something to do with this part of my code. P.S. To my knowledge, strtok returns a pointer to the token AND places a '\0' automatically right? Why is first[2] not Kristin? It is obviously separated by 2 delimiters i.e " " <- empty space. Thankyou so much!! Really appreciate the time.

```
 while(fgets(surname[i], 80, fp) != NULL) {
    surname[i] = strtok(surname[i], ",");
    if (strlen(surname[i]) >= 16) {
      surname[i][15] = '\0';
    }
    first[i] = strtok(NULL, ". ");
    if (strlen(first[i]) >= 16) {
      first[i][15] = '\0';
    }
    middle_init[i] = *(strtok(NULL, ". "));
    i++;
  }
```

All my other functions work perfectly, my error is just in reading into the 3 arrays the data from the file. Thanks!

Comment: Probably because it's working the way it's _documented._ If that differs from the way you _want_ it to, I suspect the problem lies at your end :-)

Comment: Could you please elaborate: how do you allocate memory in surname for individual lines, and how is your middle init array initilized as it should store a character `middle_init[i] = *(strtok(NULL, ". "));`

Comment: it does store a character. that part works just fine. only my first[] array is messed up for people who's surnames are greater than 16 characters of length. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a temporary buffer into `fgets` because `strtok` chops up the original string. So by using a separate string to hold the read line you will prevent unexpected results from chopping up the source string.

Also, your `if` statements seems strange. You're cutting off the strings at 16 bytes which might be what you want to do but it seems strange to do it in this code block.

Comment: That was a specification for the program! To scan 16 max characters per surname and first name! thanks though!

Comment: What do you mean by buffer??

Comment: A buffer is just a string.